# Repeating Calculator Windows blocking any other input

Tags: calculator, win10-fast-startup

The minute I login Win 10 64 bit . Effectively calculator "takes over" - cascades innumerable calculator windows prevents searches or any other input to stop the app.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a "practical joke", rather than accidental or malicious software.  First, try [starting in Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode).

- In the sign-in screen, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking the *Power* button on the lower-right to restart.
- Select *Troubleshoot* > *Advanced options* > *Startup Settings* > *Restart*.
- After restarting, select the fourth or fifth item to get Safe Mode without or with Network.

If this successfully starts the PC, you can then use an application such as Sysinternals (MS) [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to find out why *Calculator* runs at bootup and to disable it.

From Safe Mode, you could also temporarily rename the Calculator.exe file, at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1805.1201.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`, where the the path may vary with your Windows 10 version, or [uninstall it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/how-do-i-uninstall-calculator-from-windows-10/f4637ee0-a579-4de5-851e-58a246dd19c0):

- In PowerShell, enter `Get-AppxPackage *windowscalculator* | Remove-AppxPackage`.